# Circuit and schematics - grounding diode

Tags: diodes, schematics, ground

I've never seen such connection before and I was wondering why the diode is grounded in that configuration.

[image]

Comment: Inductive kickback? Perhaps there is some load with inductance conencted to it.

Comment: Given the 15 A rating, I'd guess the diode has an extra pad for thermal reasons.

Answer (score 6):

See the datasheet of the diode : [SBR15A30SP5](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/SBR15A30SP5.pdf)

You have 3 pins for the Diode: 
[image]

The Left Pin and the Right Pin must be connected to the printed circuit board. In your case they are connected to the ground.

Comment: Please explain how this answer actually answers the question

Comment: Actually it answers it very well.

Comment: @Funkyguy This question can be interpreted in two different ways: 1) Why is the diode configured so that the cathode is on the 3.3V line and the anode on the ground line (I think this is how you read it). 2) Why does the diode have two connections to ground? codo provides the answer to the second question (which is how I interpreted the initial request)

Comment: @derstrom8 Ah I see, I interpreted it as the first one.  Which one does OP want?

Comment: the diode have two anodes and one cathodes, when you use it  as a SBR diode you need to connect the two anodes to the ground.

Comment: @Funkyguy which one indeed. That is still unknown to me--I'm not sure which one he's looking for, but there are answers for both. He should have his answer one way or another =)